# Event.ctrlKey always true in material-ui library

Tags: javascript, material-ui, dom-events, mouseclick-event

I use `Table` Component from [material-ui](/questions/tagged/material-ui) library.
I set value `multiSelectable` equal true, because I need use multiselectional choice.

But selection is a little strange, because it works by default as with `ctrlKey` enabled. I need behaviour like in windows explorer (or mac finder) - without <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - select only one row, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - select several rows.

I checked code in `TableBody.js` in function `processRowSelection` - `event.ctrlKey` - is always true (use `ctrlKey` or not, if I use `shiftKey` - both are true), why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found. In file `TableRow.js` in line 74

```
event.ctrlKey = true;
```

I think the best solution - add possibility to handle this behaviour using props, not hardcode it.
Will create pull request for that.